# Given a solid conducting sphere of radius $r_A$, which has a potential $V_0$ at its surface with respect to infinity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields

Given a solid conducting sphere of radius $r_A$, which has a potential $V_0$ at its surface with respect to infinity, this sphere is placed inside a spherical shell of inner radius $r_b$ and outer radius $r_c$.

[image]

Calculate the electric field in each region of space and assume that the charge density $\rho_A$ on the sphere $A$ is known.

Find the charge density $\rho_A$ above the sphere of radius $r_A$ in terms of the radius $r_A$ ,$r_B$, $r_c$ and $V_0$

**My attempt :**

Case 1:
We going to consider a gaussian surface such that $r<r_A$, as the sphere $A$ is a conducting sphere then $\bar{E}= 0$

Case 2:
If $r_A<r<r_B$ then using gauss law we have that:

$$E_r 4\pi r^2 = \frac{Q_{enclosed}}{\epsilon_0}$$

This implies that:

$$E_r = \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0 4\pi r^2}$$

Case 3:
If $r_B<r<r_C$ then using gauss law we have that:

$$E_r 4\pi r^2 = \frac{Q_{enclosed}}{\epsilon_0}$$

Here, I'm stuck because i don't know how to calculate $Q_{enclosed}$

Can someone help me?

Comment: For $r_B<r<r_C$ you are inside the shell, and the shell is presumably conducting (it usually is in these types of question). And the electric field inside a conductor is ... ?

Comment: Is 0 @JohnRennie but the problem is i'dont know if that shell is conducting...

Comment: It typically is conducting for this problem. Also, unless the problem says otherwise, the shell is usually uncharged. That is, it has the same number of + and - charges.

Answer (score 0):

From the outside, a symmetrical sphere of charge looks like a point charge. If you know the potential at the surface, you can calculate the total charge. If the sphere is a conductor the charge will be distributed as a uniform surface charge density on the outer surface.  If the spherical shell is an uncharged conductor, the field in the conductor must be zero. There will be equal and opposite charges on the inner and outer surfaces.  Conductor or not, the field outside the shell will not be changed by the presence of an uncharged shell.